# Multichannel Convolutional Neural Network in Tensorflow

Tags: multidimensional-array, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I have a **signal** with dimensional = *(samples, height, width, channels)* and a **kernel** with dimensional = *(filter_height, filter_width, in_channels, out_channels)* to use them in a convolution operation as:

```
tf.nn.conv2d(signal, kernel, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="VALID")
```

However, *width* = *filter_width* and *channels* = *in_channels* because I'm using a text as **signal**. What I want to check is if I use a multichannel signal is the same as concatenating in the width dimension the multichannel signal and operating as one channel signal (like in the next figure) [image: word embeddings multichannel versus concatenation of word embeddings] but the output is different even sharing the **kernel** values. To explain better, I copy some code here:

```
import tensorflow as tf

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

samples = 2
n = 10
We = 5
filter_size = 4
num_filters = 20

embedding1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([samples,n,We,1], stddev=0.1))
embedding2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([samples,n,We,1], stddev=0.1))
multi_X = tf.concat([embedding1, embedding2], 3)#shape=(2, 10, 5, 2)
concat_X = tf.concat([embedding1, embedding2], 2)#shape=(2, 10, 10, 1)

W1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([filter_size, We, 1, num_filters], stddev=0.1))
W2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([filter_size, We, 1, num_filters], stddev=0.1))
multi_W = tf.concat([W1, W2], 2)#shape=(4, 5, 2, 20)
concat_W = tf.concat([W1, W2], 1)#shape=(4, 10, 1, 20)

multi_conv = tf.nn.conv2d(multi_X, multi_W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="VALID")#shape=(2, 7, 1, 20)
concat_conv = tf.nn.conv2d(concat_X, concat_W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="VALID")#shape=(2, 7, 1, 20)

init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init_op)

#sess.run(multi_conv) == sess.run(concat_conv) may be True
```

Comment: In general concatenating on the width dimension or in the channel dimension will behave differently because a convolution treats width and channel differently (the kernel is replicated across the width but has a weight for each channel)

Comment: It is true that "the kernel is replicated across the width" but if you use a _2*width_ (concatenation) or 2 channels with a _width_ (multichannel) the convolution may be the same. In fact, you use the same number of weights (both functions may have the same number of weight in the code but in different dimensions). In other words, both functions may be the same because to compute _nn.conv_ you have to use the flatten of an input fragment which is the same in the concatenated signal or in the multichannel signal.

Comment: Just because the weights are the same size doesn't mean the computation is identical.  If you look at the array syntax definition of convolution I think you'll probably see that these two statements aren't the same.  The weights in the spatial dimension are re-used across the spatial dimension of the input, and the weights along the channel dimension aren't re-used across the input channel dimension.  There are probably corner cases where the filter size is equal to the input where they are identical, but in general they are not.  I may be misunderstanding your question though.

Comment: I'm not sure if the weights are re-used through the spatial dimension. If you run the code, you can see that different weights are applied to each channel. In fact, tensorflow fails if you apply a kernel with a channel to a multichannel input. The resulting arrays are very very similar but not the same so I think the calculation is the same but I think the tensorflow internally changes the precision of the numbers in some operation.

I forgot to mention that this property can only be applied in case the input width and filter width match.